# Calculating area from Large spatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, maps, raster, area, spatial-data-frame

I have an object called cr1 which is a large SpatialPixelsDataFrame of a lake.
Here is a link to the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuvlmxmri144hp2/macrosmall.rdata?dl=0

I think each pixel has has a 1m x 1m cell size, however i think this attribute is nowhere specified. "macro" is the measured height of submersed macrophytes in the lake.
The structure looks like this.

```
    Formal class 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 7 slots

  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 252234 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ macro: num [1:252234] 0.0468 0.0518 0.0445 0.046 0.0477 ...

  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 

  ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots

  .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 3404494 5872334

  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..@ cellsize         : Named num [1:2] 1 1

  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : Named int [1:2] 776 536

  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ grid.index : int [1:252234] 415333 415334 415335 415336 415337 415338 
415339 414554 414555 414556 ...

  ..@ coords     : num [1:252234, 1:2] 3404666 3404667 3404668 3404669 3404670 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2

  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:252234] "949" "950" "951" "952" ...

  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"

  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 3404493 5872333 3405269 5872869

  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2

  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"

  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"

  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot

  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

I would like to calculate the area that is covered for certain macrophyte height intervals (i.e. the area covered for intervals of "macro").

How can I specify the resolution or size of each cell (=1m x 1m)?
Which package and function handles the area estimation of the SpatialPixelsDataFrame?

I actually only loaded the map so far

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

load("macrosmall.rdata")
```

and tried a couple of things:

```
area(cr1)
```

This would be an example of what I want and how I want to calculate it, however the specifications of the dataframe don't allow it

```
intervals <- list(c(0.1,0.2), 
              c(0.2,0.3),
              c(0.3,0.4))

sapply(intervals, function(x) { 
  sum(cr1[] > x[1] & cr1s[] <= x[2])
})
```

But I basically always end up with the same warning messages

> Warning message:
>   In .local(x, ...) :
>     This function is only useful for Raster* objects with a longitude/latitude coordinates

Please note that the area in question is quite small (25 ha).

Can anyone push me into the right direction?

Comment: The dimension is `776` and `536`, So `776 * 536 = 415936 m^2` ?

Comment: that might be for the whole rectangular area of the map. However, the lake is not rectangular and does not fill all pixels.

Comment: Just based on the code you provided, such as `area(r)`, it looks like you want the whole area. Since you did not provide a reprodicible example of your dataset, there is no way to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: I edited the original questions and added the intervals of the "macro" variable that I want to estimate the area for.

Comment: Please share the reproducible example of your data

Comment: I uploaded a crop of the file to dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuvlmxmri144hp2/macrosmall.rdata?dl=0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am really confused. You said you are working on a `spatialPixelsDataFrame`, but the data you provided, `cr1`, is a raster object.

Anyway, here I showed a possible solution to calculate the area.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

# Load the RData
load("macrosmall.RData")

# View the raster layer
cr1
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 200, 269, 53800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent      : 3405000, 3405269, 5872500, 5872700  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       : macro 
# values      : 0, 1.896009  (min, max)

# Plot the raster layer
plot(cr1)
```

[image]

I am not sure what raster values indicate the "lake". Assuming that all the non-NA cells are the lake, we can then do the following.

```
# Get all cell values
cells <- values(cr1)

# Remove NA
cells_nonNA <- cells[!is.na(cells)]

# Count how many cells
length(cells_nonNA)
# [1] 36143
```

Since 1 cell is one 1 m^2, the total lake area is `36143` m^2.

Assuming that the raster values for the lake are above 1, we can again subset the cell values.

```
cells_above1 <- cells_nonNA[cells_nonNA > 1]
length(cells_above1)
# [1] 77
```

Comment: I am sorry, I needed a fast way to crop the data as I was in a hurry. 
The objective is to calculate the area of the macrophytes. These shoudl have certain height intervals. The macrophyte values range from 0.00m to 1.89m I want to e.g. calculate area for macrophyte heights 0.1m to 0.3m, 0.3m to 0.6m, 0.6m to 1.0m, etc. 
I don't mind in which data format this happens, raster and spdf seem to be ok. It seems like the "macro" value that was present in the spdf is now the "value" shown in the raster data. Your last step can then be applied to the desired intervals. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should provide simple code-generated example data, not a file. For example

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=20, ncol=26, ext=extent(3405000, 3405269, 5872500, 5872700))
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r) / 280
set.seed(-1)
r[sample(ncell(r), 100)] <- 0
```

A solution is to first make the classes you are interested in. You can use `cut` or `reclassify`. Here with `reclassify`:

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 0.1, 1,
              0.1, 0.5, 2,
              0.5, 1, 3,
              1, 2, 4), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

rc <- reclassify(r, m)
```

And then count the number of cells in each class:

```
f <- freq(rc)
```

As long as your CRS is not longitude/latitude, you can multiply the cell count with the cell area to get the area (but in your case the area is 1, so there is be no need).

```
f <- data.frame(f)
f$area <- f$count * prod(res(rc))
```

If the data is on lon/lat, you would need to do

```
a <- area(rc)
ff <- zonal(a, rc, "sum")
```

Comment: i would have done that, if I knew how to in the first place. i might have ended up with a data structure (or parameters for certain values) different from the one I had, so that might have led to more confusion than necessary.